# OpenNLP not working with SOLR

Tags: java, solr, solr4, opennlp

I am trying to integrate OpenNLP with my SOLR project to identify Part of Speech of my tokens. I have made a custom filter which is working file if I do not make any call to OpenNLP methods. But when I try to load the "`en-pos-maxent.bin`"file using `POSModelLoader` it shows the following error

```
42908 [qtp1397843466-11] ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  û 

null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/c
ine/postag/POSModelLoader
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:717)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/cmdline/postag/POSModelLoader
        at nlp.custompos.POSTaggerCustom.POSTag(POSTaggerCustom.java:19)
        at nlp.custompos.CustomPOSNLPFilter.incrementToken(CustomPOSNLPFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:254)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:446)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1551)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:217)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:556)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:692)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:435)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:703)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:406)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: opennlp.tools.cmdline.postag.POSModelLoader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
```

I have a `CustomPOSFilter` from where I am calling the load function for `POSModelLoader`. I am creating a jar of my filter and placing it in `solr-4.5.1\example\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib` . I have included all the jars required for OpenNLP inside a lib file of this jar and included them on classpath in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I removed the NLP supporting jars from my custom jar's lib folder and added them to the WEB-INF/lib folder. Also manipulated the classpath accordingly